# How do you say “I’m getting my sister used to them.” ?

Tags: pronoms, constructions

So Collins dictionary says that **« habituer quelqu’un à... »** means **“to get somebody used to...”**.

(1) https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/habituer

Therefore, if I wanted to say **“I’m getting my sister used to these chocolates.”**, then the french sentence would be **« J’habitue ma sœur à ces chocolats. »** Thus, the sentence **“I’m getting my sister used to them.”** would be **« J’y habitue ma sœur. ».**

However, Google Translate is saying that the correct answer is **« Je m’habitue à ma sœur. »** But doesn’t that sentence mean **“I’m getting used to my sister”.** (Please look at link 2).

(2) https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/verbs-with-a/

So which is it?

(a) « J’y habitue ma sœur. » or
(b) « Je m’habitue à ma sœur. » ?

and if (b), why?

Also, if you going to explain something could you do so while bearing in mind that I’m a beginner. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: "Je m'habitue à ma soeur" = "I'm getting used to my sister"

Comment: Sans aucun intérêt pécuniaire personnel : https://www.deepl.com/translator, je n'ai pas trouvé mieux.

Answer (score 3):

You are 100% right... and Google Translate is wrong...

Comment: Thank you @Greg for the confirmation. :)

Comment: Oh yes Google Translate is wrong. Very strange "translation", it doesn't get who 'y' refers to...